# How to store a 2D array in a regular array? Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d

basically I want to be able to store a 2D array such as this

```
int [][] preferredMoves = {
            {0,0}, {0, arrLength}, {length%2, arrLength},
            {0, length%2}, {arrLength, 0}, {0, length%2}, 
            {arrLength, arrLength}, {length%2, length%2},
            {arrLength, length%2}, {length%2, 0}
    };
```

In a single

```
int [] moves;
```

array.

I'm sure this is possible since I'm just storing a list..., but I can't seem to find information on this anywhere... or maybe its not possible?

**EDIT**
I am dealing with matrices.
I want to store the list in a single array to then return that array to use it elsewhere.

So then every time I call it, all I have to do is something like this...

```
int row = Computer.moves()[0];
    int col = Computer.moves()[1];
```

I also need to loop through that single array, which contains the 2D array multiple times..

Comment: What keeps you from using an `ArrayList<int[][]>`?

Comment: you actually gave me an idea @Hips

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is what you meant,
but you could drop the internal `{ ... }` to convert this to a one-dimensional array:

```
int [] moves = {
        0, 0, 0, arrLength, length % 2, arrLength,
        0, length % 2, arrLength, 0, 0, length % 2, 
        arrLength, arrLength, length % 2, length % 2,
        arrLength, length % 2, length % 2, 0
};
```

And you can translate 2D indexes `(i, j)` to 1D index `k` using the formula:

```
k = i * 2 + j;
```

Comment: I don't quite understand this, would you mind explaining a little?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Can you please add more examples of your desired behavior?

Comment: Well I wanted to add that List to another List in order to loop through it as many times as I needed. I used an ArrayList<int[]> to do this. But then it got messy because I also wanted length to decrement which is impossible and I didn't realize until last minute... I had to redo my method a different way. Thanks though! @janos

Answer (score 0):

Janos' answer is probably what you want.  Alternatively you could create a class, e.g. `Pair`, and store it in a `Pair[]` array.